# Custom screen breakpoints bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I recently noticed that a website I am designing starts to look incredibly bad when you get below 360px. I was able to make css changes to the site when it gets below 360px using a media query. However, I was wondering if there was a way to make custom hidden and visible options as well?

My goal is to make a way to make the website look good at the smaller resolutions by hiding the current content and making visible a new set of content that is designed specifically for that size.

My second question is whether or not it is worth doing this. Would it be better practice to basically change the entire site using CSS in a media query? Another option would be to create a new page and have the user routed to that page if their screen size is < 360px. I am not sure what is considered good practice and any advice/help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the customize on bootstrap website to define your new breakpoints

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

or this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
    .xxs-hidden{
        display: none;//this is your own customised hidden class maybe?
    }


}
```

If you want to create different pages and you don't want to use the media queries to check on each screen resolution you can use jQuery to check the screen size and navigate to the html file for that screen size:

```
<script>
    if (screen.width <= 360) {
    window.location.replace("http://www.theExtraExtraSmallPage.html");
}
</script>
```

Comment: so doing your query would create a xxs-hidden class? Sorry I am pretty new to all of this so I just want to make sure I fully understand. As far as using the customize to change the breakpoints, I still want the normal breakpoints, I just want to add more.

Comment: Add your edits made it more clear. This is exactly what I want!! Thank you!

Comment: you can keep the normal break points and then create classes xxs-hidden or stuff. let me update my answer

Comment: oh ok @xCasper no problem. Have fun developing. Just mark as answer so people wont have to waste their time coming back here thinking there is no answer yet